# Failed to connect to BigQuery with Python - ServiceUnavailable

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery

querying data from BigQuery has been working for me. Then I updated my google packages (e. g. google-cloud-bigquery) and suddenly I could no longer download data. Unfortunately, I don't know the old version of the package I was using any more. Now, I'm using version '1.26.1' of google-cloud-bigquery.

Here is my code which was running:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import pandas as pd

KEY_FILE_LOCATION = "path_to_json"
PROCECT_ID = 'bigquery-123454'

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(KEY_FILE_LOCATION)
client = bigquery.Client(credentials= credentials,project=PROCECT_ID)

query_job = client.query("""
SELECT
x,
y
FROM
`bigquery-123454.624526435.ga_sessions_*` 
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20200501' AND '20200502' 
""")

results = query_job.result()

df = results.to_dataframe()
```

Except of the last line `df = results.to_dataframe()` the code works perfectly. Now I get a weired error which consists of three parts:

Part 1:

```
_InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1596627109.629000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3948,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1596627109.629000000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":394,"grpc_status":14}]}"
>
```

Part 2:

```
ServiceUnavailable: 503 failed to connect to all addresses
```

Part 3:

```
RetryError: Deadline of 600.0s exceeded while calling functools.partial(<function _wrap_unary_errors.<locals>.error_remapped_callable at 0x0000000010BD3C80>, table_reference {
  project_id: "bigquery-123454"
  dataset_id: "_a0003e6c1ab4h23rfaf0d9cf49ac0e90083ca349e"
  table_id: "anon2d0jth_f891_40f5_8c63_76e21ab5b6f5"
}
requested_streams: 1
read_options {
}
format: ARROW
parent: "projects/bigquery-123454"
, metadata=[('x-goog-request-params', 'table_reference.project_id=bigquery-123454&table_reference.dataset_id=_a0003e6c1abanaw4egacf0d9cf49ac0e90083ca349e'), ('x-goog-api-client', 'gl-python/3.7.3 grpc/1.30.0 gax/1.22.0 gapic/1.0.0')]), last exception: 503 failed to connect to all addresses
```

I don't have an explanation for this error. I don't think it has something to do with me updating the packages.

Once I had problems with the proxy but these problems caused another/different error.

My colleague said that the project "bigquery-123454" is still available in BigQuery.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:
After downgrading the package "google-cloud-bigquery" from version 1.26.1 to 1.18.1 the code worked again! So the new package caused the errors.
I downgraded the package using `pip install google-cloud-bigquery==1.18.1 --force-reinstall`

Answer (score 1):

503 error occurs when there is a network issue. Try again after some time or retry the job.
You can read more about the error on [Google Cloud Page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages)